# ¿como importar archivos de cualquier tema para que se vea correctamente como en la demo?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

siempre que instalo y activo una plantilla (tema) que me parece bonita en mi pagina se ve desconfigurada (no aparecen las imagenes ni el slider ni muchas cosas que si aparecian en la vista previa del original)..he estado viendo tutoriales pero no resuelven mi problema porque las plantillas que ellos usan son de pago y segun he visto tienen facil la opcion para importar archivos...en mis plantillas gratuitas (descargadas del mismo worpress.org) no aparece esa opcion..ya sé que cada importacion de archivos depende de la plantilla que usemenos, pero quisiera saber si existe un método universal para importar archivos de cualquier plantilla, es decir, para que mi plantilla instalada se vea identica a la demo..tampoco ayuda que la documentacion siempre esté en inglés. El tema que estoy usando ahora (gratuito, de wordpress) y aparece desconfigurado es: HITMAG

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente, algunos temas gratuitos no incluyen la opción de importar contenido de prueba, si no que es una característica exclusiva para sus ediciones de pago.

El tema del que hablas, [HitMag](https://themezhut.com/themes/hitmag/), tampoco tiene contenido de demostración para su versión gratuita. Sin embargo, si compras el tema, puedes importar el contenido de demostración así como dice en la [documentación de HitMag Pro](https://themezhut.com/hitmag-pro-wordpress-theme-documentation/#m3):

1. Primero activa e instala este plugin. – One Click Demo Import.
2. Luego ve a Escritorio > Apariencia > "Import Demo Data".
3. Click en el botón “Import Demo Data”.

Si quieres comprar el tema, lo puedes hacer desde [su sitio web](https://themezhut.com/themes/hitmag/). Espero te ayude esta información.

Comment: hola ¿para que me sirve ese plugin, si no existe el archivo .xml para importar? ya seguí todos los pasos y al final me dice: "No import files specified!"...............y arriba dice "There are no predefined import files available in this theme. Please upload the import files manually!".........Y otra pregunta: ¿TODOS los temas de pago vienen con el archivo xml que te permite importar la demo? es que no quisiera cometer el error de comprar un tema que al final no me traiga la opcion de importar demo..por eso quiero saber si no debo preocuparme por eso, si todos lo traen

Comment: Hola, como te escribí en la respuesta, este tema **no tiene un archivo xml para importar en su versión gratuita**. Sin embargo, **en su versión de pago SI tiene datos de demostración para importar**. Si necesitas estos datos de prueba, te recomiendo comprar el tema.

Comment: ah yo pense que me estabas dando una solucion con ese plugin, pero supongo es para cuando lo compre......lo voy a desinstalar entonces.. y la otra pregunta que te hice ¿todos los temas de pago vienen con la opcion de importar demo (todos tiene su documento .xml)?

Comment: Mira, la mayoría si, pero en realidad varía por tema. Para estar 100% seguro, puedes leer las características del tema o ver su documentación antes de comprar.

Comment: ok. gracias... si porque la gracia de la plantilla es que te venga como en la demo para que te puedas guiar facilmente en su personalizacion..no entiendo porque vienen desconfiguradas por defecto, si todo el mundo habla de que worpress es muy fail, pero a la hora de la hora, hay varias cosas complicaditas que no te dicen

Comment: Claro, es cierto lo que dices, pero recuerda que el tema tiene su documentación donde te expican (más o menos) en que lugar va cada cosa. Y tambien, ten en cuenta de que esto es un negocio, así que no perderán la oportunidad de cobrarte por datos de demostración...

Comment: solo que estan en ingles la mayoria :/...pero igual no me vas a negar que en algunos temas tienes que realizar muchisimos procesos como instalaciones e importaciones para que la plantilla se vea como prometen en la demo.. o sea no es nada sencillo.. es aburrido, y no deberia ser asi.......en fin yo estoy probando a ver si me puedo adaptar a worpress, pero en rrealidad no me gusta nada..y si se me va la paciencia pues seguire haciendo webs a medida (sin cms) o me retirare del negocio de la web

Comment: Bueno, lamentablemente para el negocio web (y de la programación) es casi necesario el inglés, y si, también en algunos temas es bastante molesto el proceso para instalar los contenidos de prueba, pero generalmente, en el caso de **comprar** un tema, el simplemente instalar el tema, instalar los plugins e instalar el contenido de prueba para que quede listo para usar.

Comment: ese plugin que me recomendaste es para que cuando tenga el tema comprado automáticamente me detecte el archivo xml para importar, no??...porque viendo en tutoriales tambien se puede hacer de forma manual, es decir, ir a las carpetas de la plantilla, buscar el xml e importarlo al worpress

Comment: Mira, no te recomendé un plugin, si no que copié lo que decía la documentación del tema. El tema viene con el plugin para importar preinstalado. Esto es muy común entre los temas que traen la opción de importar.

Comment: ah ya entendi..pero ese plugin solo sirve para la plantilla de pago.......ok gracias, no le quito mas tiempo

Comment: No te preocupes, disculpa si no me expliqué bien